# Why query inside the function not working correctly?

Tags: postgresql

I have this query which returns me students have at least two marks less than 3

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM result r 
 JOIN student s ON r.student_id = s.student_id 
GROUP BY s.name 
HAVING COUNT(mark <= 3) > 2;
```

I have this result:

```
1 "John1"
2 "John10"
3 "John100"
4 "John1000"
5 "John10000"
6 "John100000"
7 "John10001"
8 "John10002"
9 "John10003"
10 "John10004"
```

But when I create a function based on those query, which looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.red_zone()
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    VOLATILE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100
    AS $BODY$
      SELECT s.name 
      FROM result r 
        JOIN student s ON r.student_id = s.student_id 
      GROUP BY s.name 
      HAVING COUNT(mark <= 3) > 2;
    $BODY$;

SELECT red_zone();
```

I have this result:

```
1 "John1"
```

Why is this happening? How it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined that your function `RETURNS character varying` which is a single value. What you want is `RETURNS SETOF character varying` and then treat it as a table or other row source.

```
SELECT * FROM red_zone();
```

Answer (score 0):

RETURNS character varying is the mistake